# Set a SQL trigger and have asp.net subscribe to it?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to set a SQL trigger, where if it gets fired, do something in an asp.net application?

Comment: Please, have a look at my answer. I think it's interesting enough.

Comment: I think your answer is very promising. I will have to set up a SQL dependency and see if it works the way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Theoretically YES (via SQL CLR Stored Proc calling a web service in
  that asp.net app)
- Psychologically NO

You'd be better using a queue or log table, write to that and have a service or task subscribe to it.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on why is it bad to take the approach number 1 (the SQL CLR proc) ? Is it because that is not the way its generally done? Or are there technical reasons (like maintainability etc) ?

Comment: bit of both. generally in a production environment your sql server wouldn't have visibility to your website. You have to jump through quite a few hoops to get all this setup - tweaks to sql and security changes. And, you are introducing quite a big point of failure into your system.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I am glad that I got a response from someone who actually knows what he is talking about. (As opposed to many people who just throw philosophies out there and have no clue.)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Excuse me... taht technology is deprecated, and now you should use:
[SQL Dependency class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)

DEPRECATED:

You can use SQL Server Notification Service.

Look at this article:

[Understanding SQL Server 2005 Notification Services with ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspalliance.com/1541_Understanding_SQL_Server_2005_Notification_Services_with_ASPNET_20)

It uses right the same technology that [SqlCacheDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) which could also help you, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.